# Creating 3 tables in a databse ( retrieve data php/mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Hello I have been facing a slight problem how to effectively create the databse for this case:

I. Database schemes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `songs` (
`url` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`author` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=293 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`login` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`social_fb` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`social_yt` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `playlists` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`accountid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`songs` varchar(10000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

II. Ideology.

Each user(account) can have multiple playlists. The playlists will contain songs stored with id in 'songs'.

III. Conclusion

1) Im more than sure this db scheme isn't fixed for this kind of issue. I don't know how it could get the songs.id into the playlist table and assign that for a user. Could you please help me and explain how should it look like?

2) Possible query for retrieving a single playlist out of user
  a) Get the id's of playlists assigned to a user account.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: And what is your question.?

Comment: You need another table that will associate a song_id with a playlist_id (instead of storing the songs in a string)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a fourth table called playlist_has_song or something like that where you map which songs are in which playlist. Then you can delete the *songs* column in the *playlists* table.

So you have:

```
table: song
-----------
id (PK)
url
author
name

table: account
--------------
id (PK)
login
password
social_fb
social_yt

table: playlist
---------------
id (PK)
accountid (FK to account.id)

table: playlist_has_song
------------------------
playlistid (FK to playlist.id)
songid (FK to song.id)
```

Please note that a name of a table is always singular and not plural.

### Queries

Get the id's of playlists assigned to a user account:

```
SELECT id FROM playlist WHERE userid = ?
```

Comment: I know what are fk and pk but is there a sql command to make it faster? The relation model in phpmysql is bit hard for me

Comment: I basically don't know how to set it up on mysql..

Comment: You can use a tool like [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) or study the syntax of [mysqls create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html)

Comment: I used phpmysql check out this I dont know how to set the relations maybe u can help http://oi44.tinypic.com/xbmpav.jpg

Comment: Relations are not needed to get your script working. What's insid the select boxes?

Comment: f.e in account id
leagueofmusic`.`account`.`id`
leagueofmusic`.`playlist`.`id`
leagueofmusic`.`song`.`id`

Comment: Okay. account and song do not need any relations. For the table playlist select for the column accountid "`leagueofmusic`.account.id" and for playlist_has_song select for column "playlistid" "`leagueofmusic`.playlist.id" and for the column "songid" "`leagueofmusic`.song.id"

Comment: Think its ok http://oi44.tinypic.com/6fck84.jpg tell me now 2 queries to get the playlist's ( not 1 ) id from a account and then the query to dump out the song id's from playlist attached to the account:3

Comment: A query to get all playlist ids for a user I wrote above in my answer. The other would be something like: `SELECT songid, playlistid
FROM playlist_has_song phs
LEFT JOIN playlist p ON p.id = phs.playlistid
WHERE p.accountid = ?`

Comment: Yes its that what I needed :) 1 more thing (last) could you try somehow get the name/url/author ? cause it will be for my php file

Comment: `SELECT songid, playlistid, s.name, s.author, s.url
FROM playlist_has_song phs 
LEFT JOIN playlist p ON p.id = phs.playlistid 
LEFT JOIN song s ON s.id = phs.songid
WHERE p.accountid = ?`

Comment: Oh the phs table wrote me a alert  This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Simply can't edit it - I need that option though

Comment: you have to add a PK with the columns songid and playlistid in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your playlists table should not have a column that holds all the songs in the playlist as you have attempted. Instead, create a child table like playlist_song that has a row per playlist, per song. That will become the list of songs. Something like:

```
playlist_song (
  playlist_id int,
  song_id int
)
```